# Start process on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, process, mono

I want to write command in Mac equivalent to "ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi" in Windows. My code is:

```
Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                Arguments = "-i /Users/John/Desktop/input.avi     /Users/John/Desktop/hhh.avi",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
```

After I write "mono previousCode.exe" in the terminal in Mac, I get "filename unknown" error.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: I have a folder 'ffmpeg' in the directory 'John', but I can't find the exe on my Mac.

I tried writing FileName = "/Users/John/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", instead of FileName = "ffmpeg.exe", but it still didn't work.

Comment: On OSX does the executable really end in .exe?

Comment: Well i Can't find .exe or .dmg

Comment: Can you run the command from the command line in Terminal and what is the working command line

Comment: Mac's don't have "exes."  If you right click your application, you can view the "Package Contents."  In there you can find the "Unix Executable File" for your application.

Comment: ffmpeg -i /Users/John/Desktop/input.avi     /Users/John/Desktop/hhh.avi

is the line that works on Mac written directly in terminal.

Comment: If I go right click on the folder 'ffmpeg', it doesn't have the option to view the package contents. However, when I open it, I can find a few files which are Unix executable files. Their names are configure, ffprobe_g, etc.

Comment: OMG, I actually solved it. I can't believe what was the problem.
The correct line is:

Process.Start("ffmpeg", "-i /Users/John/Desktop/ughh.avi /Users/John/Desktop/comeOn.avi");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executables in MacOS generally don't end with a .exe suffix, so just leave off the ".exe" and see if that works. If not, you'll need to provide the full path to `ffmpeg`

Comment: Yeah, I already found that out the hard way :)
I actually wrote it as a comment to my question.